# Iterative integration with indicator function

Tags: integration, iterated-integrals

I have an exercice in which the result
$$
\int_{[0,1]^n}\mathbf{1}_{\{0<x_n<\ldots<x_2<x_1<1\}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\mathrm{d}x_k=\frac{1}{n!}
$$
is given in a development like it's obvious, which to me is not. So I've tried to verify this for $n=2, 3$ and it does indeed seem to hold: (for instance with $n=2$)
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathbf{1}_{\{0<z<y<1\}}\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}y
 &=
  \int_{0}^{1}\left[\int_{0}^{y}\mathbf{1}_{\{0<y<1\}}\mathrm{d}z\right]\mathrm{d}y\\
 &=
  \int_{0}^{1}\left[z\mathbf{1}_{\{0<y<1\}} \right]_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}y\\
 &=
  \int_{0}^{1}y\mathbf{1}_{\{0<y<1\}}  \mathrm{d}y\\
 &=
  \int_{0}^{1}y \mathrm{d}y=\left[\frac{y^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{1}\\
 &=
  \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Given (one of) Fubini's theorem, the order of integration shouldn't matter, but when I flip the order, I don't get the same result. I suppose something is off with the way I manipulate the indicator functions (quite possibly the presence of the integration variable in it), but anyway, here's my attempt:

\begin{align*}
 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathbf{1}_{\{0<z<y<1\}}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z
  &=
   \int_{0}^{1}\left[\int_{z}^{1}\mathbf{1}_{\{0<z<y\}}\mathrm{d}y\right]\mathrm{d}z\\
  &=
   \int_{0}^{1}\left[y\mathbf{1}_{\{0<z<y\}} \right]_{z}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\\
  &=
   \int_{0}^{1} (1-z)\mathbf{1}_{\{0<z<y\}} \mathrm{d}z\\
  &=
   \int_{0}^{y} (1-z)  \mathrm{d}z=\left[z-\frac{z^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{y}\\
  &=
   y-\frac{y^2}{2}
 \end{align*}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mess thing up with indicators in your second derivation.  After $\int_0^1[y1_{\{0<z<y\}}]^1_z dz$ there should be $\int_0^1 (1-z)dz$ not $\int_0^1 (1-z)1_{\{0<z<y\}}dz$ (you cannot have $y$ after integration with respect to $y$. All terms with $y$ should have vanished). In fact, there is no point with those indicators after you've plugged everything into limits of integration.

Comment: This may help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration   .    Try the inverse process. (Define the $\frac{1}{n!}$, with taking $f(x)$ in wikipedia formula to be indicator). You'll get the same thing, you did.

Comment: @kolobokish Nice, thanks for the link!

Comment: @Dominik Kutek, Yes, makes sense, I suspected something of that sort; thanks as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't leave it in when you take it out.

You have the bound variable of the inner integral occurring in the bounds of the outer integral.    It certainly should *not* be there.

Your issue is that during the process of "integrating out" the bound variable $y$ you left it inside the indicator domain.

---

In short: $0<z<y<1$ exactly when we have $z\in(0..1)$ and $y\in(z..1)$, so:

$$\begin{align}\iint_{\Bbb R^2}\mathbf 1_{0<z<y<1} \,\mathrm d\langle y, z\rangle &=\int_\Bbb R \mathbf 1_{0<z<1}\int_z^1\mathrm dy\,\mathrm d z\\& =\int_0^1\int_z^1 \mathrm dy\,\mathrm d z\\[1ex] &= \int_0^1 (1-z)\,\mathrm d z\\[1ex]&= (z-\tfrac 12z^2)\big\vert_{z=0}^{z=1}\\[1ex]&= (1-\tfrac 12)-(0-\tfrac 120)\\[1ex]&= \tfrac 12 \end{align}$$

---

Compare that to how it was initially done, where it is observed that we have $0<z<y<1$ exactly when we have $y\in(0..1)$ and $z\in(0..y)$, so:

$$\begin{align}\iint_{\Bbb R^2}\mathbf 1_{0<z<y<1} \,\mathrm d\langle y, z\rangle &=\int_\Bbb R \mathbf 1_{0<y<1}\int_0^y\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d y\\& =\int_0^1\int_0^y \mathrm dz\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex] &= \int_0^1 y\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&= (\tfrac 12y^2)\big\vert_{y=0}^{y=1}\\[1ex]&= \tfrac 12 \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the integral as $\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{x_1}\int\limits_0^{x_2}...\int\limits_0^{x_{n-1}}dx_n...dx_2dx_1$ where the indicator function is used to set the limits.